# Dynamically attaching validation in directive does not update class

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to dynamically toggle validation in form by attaching a validation directive to an element under certain conditions. This works as intended, the input field is either valid or invalid depending if the directive is attached or not and is valid. However, when I add or remove the directive, the input field looses it's $dirty and $touched. I have an ng-class directive in there that should change the class depending on the validity and it does not work.

The input field looks like this, the validateLogic function returns true or false.

```
<input 
   name="testInput" 
   type="text"
   ng-class="{'error': testForm.testInput.$invalid && testForm.testInput.$dirty }"
   ng-model="testInput" 
   attach-directive="{'validate-test': validateLogic() }" 
/>
```

And the directive itself looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('attachDirective', function($compile, $timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.attachDirective, attachWatchAction, true);

        function attachWatchAction(newValue) {
            angular.forEach(newValue, function (value, key) {
                if (value) {
                    if (!element.attr(key)) {
                        var inputVal    = element.val();
                        element.attr(key, true);
                        $compile(element)(scope);

                        $timeout(function () {
                            element.val(inputVal);
                            scope.$apply();
                        }, 0);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (element.attr(key)) {
                        element.removeAttr(key);
                        $compile(element)(scope);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oligustafsson/f1wooqd5/

Input should read "test" to validate

Removing the attach directive and just have the validate directive works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, in the validation I could set it to $dirty:

```
ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
    var valid = value === 'test';
    ctrl.$setValidity('validateTest', valid);

    if(!valid && value !== '') {
        ctrl.$dirty = true;
        ctrl.$pristine = false;
        ctrl.$touched = true;
        ctrl.$untouched = true;
    }

    return value;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oligustafsson/10gfnpe2/